# error with resolve module fs in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am new with react native and while i am working with it there is error appeared suddnally that's say

```
While trying to resolve module `fs` from file  `/Users/saramuneef/maghnaApp/Maghna/node_modules/istanbul-lib-report/lib/context.js`, the     package `/Users/saramuneef/maghnaApp/Maghna/node_modules/fs/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/saramuneef/maghnaApp/Maghna/node_modules/fs/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

   * /Users/saramuneef/maghnaApp/Maghna/node_modules/fs/index.js(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * /Users/saramuneef/maghnaApp/Maghna/node_modules/fs/index.js/index(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
 Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

I am trying many things to siloed it but still appear

Comment: Where are you importing `fs` package?

Comment: can you post the import statement?

Comment: there is "react-native-fs" in packer-lock.json    "react-native-fs": {
      "version": "2.16.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-fs/-/react-native-fs-2.16.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ZWOooD1AuFoAGY3HS2GY7Qx2LZo4oIg6AK0wbC68detxwvX75R/q9lRqThXNKP6vIo2VHWa0fYUo/SrLw80E8w==",
      "requires": {
        "base-64": "^0.1.0",
        "utf8": "^3.0.0"
      }